# What would something be which fails to provide traceability?

Tags: phrase-requests

If something fails to provide **security** it is said to be *insecure*.

So what would something be which fails to provide **traceability**?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you are looking for [untraceable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/untraceable)

> incapable of being traced or tracked down; "an untraceable source".

Answer (score 3):

How about `untraceable`?

(body must be at least 30 characters)

Comment: Generally, if you find that you are not meeting the 30 character limit, you probably haven't provided enough information for a good answer. One thing that you could do to help flesh out your answer is address why you think "untraceable" is a good fit for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Untraceable for sure with reference

or

unfindable with reference

[reference 1](http://global.christianpost.com/news/joe-giudice-still-owes-former-business-partner-260000-stemming-from-2007-case-101331/)

[reference 2](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/untraceable)

Comment: If you are using a long article or similar as a reference, please quote the relevant sentence in your answer to avoid the need for others to read through or search your quoted source.

Comment: @TrevorD..yeah you are right but when I'm using this technique my answer downvoted..and asked me for reference so I directly give this type of reference..

Comment: You can always amend the answer.